# Is there a way to see who & how grades your Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

Being a developer of an app, I would naturally like to find who downgrades it and stop buying this traffic:
[E.g.: I gave 5* to Agario.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADY89.png)